# Where's Win10's Registry for Desktop wallpaper, Desktop icons and Tasbar icons?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, taskbar, desktop

In my company we got a computer which "barely" runs.
Anytime it is rebooted the desktop is wiped so that the wallpaper, all icons, start icons and taskbar has the default stuff on it. (My boss knows, but he doesn't care, so fixing it is not an option)

I was hoping we could be able to just set up the desktop and pinned icons on the taskbar like we want, save the registry keys as .reg files and then simply "run" the registry file to install the keys as we had them before.

Now i looked some info up already. Apparently destop icons should be in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`. 
Taskbar should be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`.
Both of which seem to be the same on my computer, Yet not exactly as in the images shown on those websites. Maybe because i use Display fusion. Not sure.

Now according to some pages the wallpaper should be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\TranscodedImageCache`
But on my machine neither paths exist in my registry.

Does anyone know where they might be otherwise? or perhaps a workaround for that?
cheers~

ps: Before anyone asks, the computer we are using is a beater, so our boss doesn't mind if we fiddle with it as long as we don't phisically break it.

Comment: If Windows is not central to your use case, maybe run from a live Linux USB stick. You can make your environment preferences stick; see e.g. [Ubuntu's (community-maintained) guideline.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence)

Comment: Changing OS is not an option either. We need software which only runs on windows